# Good articles for Sharepoint Web Part creation?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

Does anyone know of any good basic articles for creating Sharepoint Web Parts.

I have found a couple, but most of them jumped in a little quick.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MSDN: Developing Web Parts in Windows SharePoint Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms367238.aspx)

[Write Custom WebParts for SharePoint 2007](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/webforms/article.php/c12293/)

[Writing Custom Web Parts for SharePoint 2007](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/09/02/Writing-Custom-Web-Parts-for-SharePoint-2007.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

For once, I can absolutely say that microsoft has done a good job at this.  It is like they grabbed a student from a CS technical writing class and had them write a step by step so that us average folks understand it.
Walkthrough: Creating a Basic SharePoint Web Part:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452873.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

- [SharePoint developer portal](http://www.microsoft.com/click/SharePointDeveloper/)
- [SharePoint forums @ MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/threads/)
- [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/Project/ProjectDirectory.aspx?TagName=Sharepoint) to look at others code

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much the same as ASP.NET 2.0 web parts. If you're having trouble getting started, you can check out the [ASP.Net 2.0 tutorials](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/webparts/default.aspx).

There's also a way to load UserControls into your webpart, so your usercontrol does the heavy lifting and the webpart is just a wrapper to play nice with Sharepoint.

[LoadControl vs SmartPart](http://weblogs.asp.net/erobillard/archive/2008/03/04/what-to-know-about-smartpart-and-loadcontrol.aspx)